# How could I make a rotating image alternate in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to make a rotating image move with mouseX and mouseY and interact with key-commands: When the left or right arrow keys are pressed, the  images should alternate between each other; the up arrow increases the rotation speed, while the down arrow should decrease rotation speed.

Applied some edits based on responses, but nothing displays when I run the code.

Amended code listed below:

```
var angle = 0.0;
var angleSpeed = 0.0;
var imageSwitcher = 0;
var images = [];
var img1;
var img2;
var img3;

function preload() {
  images[0] = loadImage(image1);
  images[1] = loadImage(image2);
  images[2] = loadImage(image3);

function setup() {  
  createCanvas(900, 500);  
  background(100);
}

function draw() {  
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);  
  rotate(angle);  
  images(imageSwitcher % 2,-15, -15, 30, 30); 
  angle += angleSpeed;
}
  
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
    images = img1;
  }
  else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW) {
    images = img2;
  }
  else if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
    images = img3; 
  }
  else if (keyCode == UP_ARROW) {
    angleSpeed += 1.0;
  }
  else if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW) {
    angleSpeed -= 1.0;
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var angle = 0.0;
var angleSpeed = 0.0;
var images = [];
var imageSwitcher = 0;

function preload() {
  images[0] = loadImage("ToyStoryLogo.png");
  images[1] = loadImage("CarsLogo.png");
  images[2] = loadImage("Incredibles.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 500);
  background(204);
}

function draw() {
  background(204);
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);
  rotate(angle);
  image(images[abs(imageSwitcher) % 3], -15, -15, 30, 30);
  angle += angleSpeed;
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
    imageSwitcher--;
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW) {
    imageSwitcher++;
  } else if (keyCode == UP_ARROW) {
    angleSpeed += 0.1;
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW) {
    angleSpeed -= 0.1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get the images to repeat/draw as they move? I started with a basic code that drew a rectangle in-place as the cursor moved.

Comment: Do you mean repeat like leave a trail?

Comment: Yep, and I accidentally figured it out. Just had to remove the background from the draw function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that I see.
The first has to do with the rotation speed control.
You want to add a variable to control the incrementation of the angle variable.
Create a variable, lets say angleSpeed.
var angle = 0.0;
var angleSpeed = 0.0;
...
In the draw function, change the line
angle += 0.1;
to
angle += angleSpeed;

This allows you to control the rotation in keyPressed( );

if keycode Up
angleSpeed += 1.0;
If keycode Down
angleSpeed -= 1.0;

Switching through the images would be a little more complicated. I would look into creating a array of images,
var images = [ ];

Then cycling through the array with a key press right or left.
var image = [ ]
var ImageSwitcher = 0
Then in preload
images[0] = loadImage (image1);
images[1] = loadImage (image2);
images[2] = loadImage (image3);

```
In draw 
    image(images[imageSwitcher % 3], x,y,...);
```

For keycode right arrow
ImageSwitcher++;
For keycode left arrow
ImageSwitcher--

Comment: Thank you for helping with the angleSpeed! I was going to avoid doing an array and use the keyPressed function, but if the array would make it operate better, how exactly would I go about it?

Comment: If you only had two pictures, the Right Arrow and Left Arrow would be fine to just select a photo. Since you have three, in your current code the img3 would never be reached. Ill edit my answer to include the array solution.

Comment: To clarify, am I just declaring the global variable "image" or does it have a value? Same for function preload; couldn't I just input `loadImage (image1)` or does that have to be preceded by the `images[0] = loadImage`?

Comment: It would be global declaration var images = []; this creates and array named images. In preload you add the images by index. So images[0] is the first image and so on. Instead of img1 you have images[0], img2 is images[1]; img3 is images[2]

Comment: I'm posting my amended code above.  It looks like everything is in order, but nothing is displaying when I run it in p5.js.

Comment: I had holes in my explanation so I wrote it out and tried it myself, I posted another answer, that should do it.